# Using ES6 imports to add methods to a class prototype yields errors with 'this'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following two files:

```
// push.js
export default (item) => {
  this.items.push(item);
};
```

-

```
// index.js
import push from './push';

class pushy {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }
}

pushy.prototype.push = push;

export default pushy;
```

The intended effect would be for the exported `pushy` to have a `push` method available, that would push to `this.items`. The actual result however is an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

The errors shows that `this` seems to be an issue.

Now interestingly, if one were to revert back to `require` and `module.exports` everything works perfectly as expected.

```
// push.js
module.exports = function(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
};
```

-

```
// index.js
function pushy() {
  this.items = [];
}

pushy.prototype.push = require('./push');

module.exports = pushy;
```

As far as I can tell both versions should be the same, yet they are not. Is there a way to make this work with ES6 or will I have to resort to using old syntax?

Comment: do you know what `this` will be when using arrow `=>` function? What do you expect it will be in that code in push.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is that they bind the lexical `this` value and never let it go. Because of this, you can't use them in this case. You do have to use function expressions (or declarations) for functions in which the `this` value will vary.

There's nothing wrong with using function expressions. They may not look as nice (in my opinion) but they're really just another tool.

Comment: @aFreshMelon Haha no worries. Trust me, I wish I could use them everywhere but just toggle it somehow to avoid binding the `this` value.

Comment: Oh yeah, mixing both seems like a mess.